# Redux Store does not update state with created data on firebase real-time database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have setup my firebase functions and it works perfectly. The data flow for my app goes thus:

1. User fills a form and submits {works}
2. The data is sent to the real-time database {works}
3. The data is then passed back to the redux store by listening to the database ref. {does not work}
4. The data is then displayed in a table true the redux store for the user to see his/her submitted info. {does not work because 3 does not work}

Where I'm experiencing the issue is number 3.

Here is my Redux action file:

```js
import {
  SAVE_FORM,
  UPDATE_STORE
} from "./types";

export const saveForm = user => {
  return {
    type: SAVE_FORM,
    payload: user
  };
};

export const updateStore = data => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_STORE,
    payload: data
  };
};
```

And here is my reducer:

```js
import {
  SAVE_FORM,
  UPDATE_STORE
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  users: [],
  db: ""
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SAVE_FORM:
      return {
        ...state,
        users: [action.payload]
      };

    case UPDATE_STORE:
      return {
        db: [action.payload]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And finally my sagas file:

```js
import {
  database
} from "./firebase-config"
import axios from "axios"
import {
  put,
  fork,
  takeEvery,
  take
} from 'redux-saga/effects'
import {
  eventChannel
} from "redux-saga"
import {
  SAVE_FORM,
  UPDATE_STORE
} from "./actions/types"

export function* sendRequest({
  payload
}) {
  //console.log(payload);
  yield axios.post('https://dummy.com/user', payload)
    .then(res => {
      // here will be code
      console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};

export function* watchSendAction() {
  yield takeEvery(SAVE_FORM, sendRequest);
}

function createEventChannel() {
  const listener = eventChannel(emit => {
    database.ref('entries/users').on('value', data => emit(data.val()));
    return () => database.ref('entries/users').off(listener);
  });
  return listener;
}

//This is supposed to update my store with the data received by the database
function* startListener() {
  const updateChannel = createEventChannel();
  while (true) {
    const data = yield takeEvery(updateChannel);
    yield put(UPDATE_STORE(data));
  }
}


export default function* helloSaga() {
  yield fork(watchSendAction);
  yield fork(startListener);
}
```

I can't seem to figure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: firstly, your reducer `UPDATE_STORE` is not the same as your initial state, can you please fix it to reflect your payload.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @AbdeenM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is in your `startListener` saga. You should use either while cycle with the `take` effect or use `takeEvery` without while cycle. Right now you are mixing the two together.

Try this:

```
function* startListener() {
  const updateChannel = createEventChannel();
  while (true) {
    const data = yield take(updateChannel);
    yield put(UPDATE_STORE(data));
  }
}
```

or this:

```
function* startListener() {
  const updateChannel = createEventChannel();
  yield takeEvery(updateChannel, function*(data) {
    yield put(UPDATE_STORE(data));
  });
}
```